# Search not working in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

Good afternoon,

We use SharePoint to store our important docs.
One of my users contacted me complaining that his searches were not working.

I thought that I may have an issue with crawling so I went to
Central Administration > Application Management section > Manage Service Applications.

I clicked the Search service application and I got this:

---

Sorry, something went wrong
The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration' is not allowed for this page. The type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe.
Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 92a4b29f-3971-a08a-6a37-4590b38f1afb

Date and Time: 3/9/2021 12:50:13 PM

---

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks

Christophe

Comment: Have you recently installed SharePoint updates?

Comment: This also sounds like a missing update, i.e. installed perhaps the non-locale specific update while missing the locale update from the same month.

Comment: See a post here for similar error for possible solution: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/165426/the-base-type-39microsoftofficeserversearchinterna.html

Comment: My SharePoint is up to date

Comment: @MASServices Have you checked the solution provided in the post? Also in this one: https://azurecloudai.blog/2012/09/13/the-base-type-microsoft-office-server-search-internal-ui-searchfarmdashboard-is-not-allowed-for-this-page-the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was this post: https://azurecloudai.blog/2012/09/13/the-base-type-microsoft-office-server-search-internal-ui-searchfarmdashboard-is-not-allowed-for-this-page-the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe/

Comment: You can accept this Answer if you confirm it to be the solution.