# Sharepoint 2019 Search Service not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, 2019

Having this issue since couple days. Search was working fine before that. Getting below error.

[image]

I already tried couple things from some posts.

Added the following to the web.config file.

> SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI" TypeName="*" Safe="True"
>
> SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration" TypeName="*" Safe="True"
>
> PageParserPath
> VirtualPath="/searchadministration.aspx"
> CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true"

Still no luck accessing the search service to perform a crawl since list and site search not getting any results back.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you added those SafeControls to the web.configs on all SharePoint servers?

Comment: I added only one one front end for testing. where the CA was started. Do i need to add on all the front end web.configs? OR all the servers i have including app server.

Comment: I imagine it needs to be added to all SharePoint servers but particularly those serving end user requests.

Comment: Callum, i have added on all the front end servers this time, but of no luck. Any other ideas you have?

Comment: An IIS reset might be required on the servers, since the web.config has changed.

Comment: I have restarted the servers but of no luck,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following line into the central administration web site web.config:

```
<SafeControl        
   Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0,        
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"        
   Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI"        
   TypeName="*" 
/>
    
<PageParserPath        
   VirtualPath="/searchadministration.aspx"        
   CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true"        
/>
```

Remember to add < /> to the code.
Reference: [Search not working in SharePoint 2019](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290703/search-not-working-in-sharepoint-2019)

Comment: Amy thanks for your reply. I already added the suggested lines in the CA web.config file. But of no luck. Is there anyything else you can suggest. I did add < /> AS WELL.

Comment: It is recommended to modify Version=15.0.0.0 to Version=16.0.0.0 and try it out.

Comment: Amy, i have tried adding the suggested version as well but of no luck, any other suggestions. thanks

Comment: You can try again according to the method provided in this article: https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/fixed-the-base-type-search-ui-searchresultslayoutpage-is-not-allowed-for-this-page/
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for the answer, you need to just add the single line below to between the safecontrols tags of all web.config files, then recycle the application pools in IIS. Note that the version number is 16, not 15.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```